# Would an Intel Core2 Duo Processor SU7300 (1.30GHz, 3MB L2, 800MHzFSB) be okay for Java programming on the go?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for a light small laptop for java/grails programming on the go (travelling to and from work - approx 1.5 hrs each way).

The Intel Core2 Duo Processor SU7300 (1.30GHz, 3MB L2, 800MHzFSB) seems cost effective and battery friendly, but can it handle running the likes of eclipse/netbeans/idea reasonably?

As soon as you move up to an i5, the price and battery start getting hammered.

I'm planning on having an SSD drive, so I expect that to make the machine snappy, but I've got no idea if I'd be wasting my time on an SU7300.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** I went with a MacBook Air, Core2Duo 1.8GHz. I'll try to write up a blog post comparing:

- MacBook Air 2.18GHz SSD (friends)
- MacBook Air 1.8GHz SSD (mine)
- Dell Inspiron 15R i5 7200rpm disk (wifes)
- Dell Inspiron 1525 Core2Duo 1.8GHz 7200rpm disk (my old laptop)

I'll pick and compare : a suitable opensource maven library to build, a grails application, and launch times for the IDEs, and try to find other suitable programmer tasks to compare etc. Pity I don't have an SU7300 available to compare!

Comment: That CPU may be a little lightweight for what you need. However, it depends on your idea of "reasonably", and there's the SSD ... I dunno, it may be fine, but I'd prefer to go nearer the 2GHz side if I could.

Comment: Since this really isn't a programming related question, perhaps it fits better under superusers?

Comment: The CPU is strong enough. Buy lots of RAM as well, I bet you'll be starting server processes from within eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - planning on 4GB ram, and installing an 80GB SSD myself http://www.computerwholesale.com.au/?398749

Comment: Sorry, probably should have posted on SuperUsers. Can I move it or do I re-ask it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an entire Java operating system that requires less than what you are talking about:

http://www.jnode.org/node/573

Comment: You can also try Haskell, which is faster, faster to program in, and easier to maintain, much less bug prone, etc.

Comment: Heh, I'm looking for a laptop that can handle java programming. Not an operating system. But I appreciate the lateral thinking. Switching languages/environments to suit a laptop is not an option. It would be cheaper just to by a top end laptop. Anyhoo, I've bought a MacBook Air. Thanks.